# Exact Match search from Mysql FullText Search

Tags: mysql

By Using Full Text Search not searching the exact value for multiple words.
This is the Query

```
  SELECT * FROM csv WHERE match(data) against('"TMN PANTAI"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Its showing the result but its searching with "TMN" and "PANTAI" and "TMN PANTAI"

How can i search the exact match using "TMN PANTAI"?

Answer (score 8):

`FULL-TEXT` doesn't take space into consideration, that is why you cannot use it.

If you still want to take advantage of full-text index, you can shorten up the resultset by filtering using `match against query` and add an additional `LIKE` condition. This will be efficient than querying with `LIKE` on the whole table, since the `LIKE` will now have lesser records to filter.

```
SELECT * FROM csv WHERE match(data) against('+TMN +PANTAI' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AND data like '%TMN PANTAI%'
```

Comment: its searching the text from the fields.using  Just replacement  for like %TMN PANTAI%

Comment: @ManmeetKhurana Updated the answer. Try this.

Comment: its not working have already try, Its give the results "TMN" OR "PANTAI"  by using against('+TMN +PANTAI' IN BOOLEAN MODE) .but i want to match the result "TMN PANTAI"

Comment: Try the 2nd suggestion in the answer

Comment: ,its searching with single string same as "TMN" as "PANTAI" .Is their any solution regarding exact match ?give result according to "TMN PANTAI"

Comment: Use like. SELECT * FROM csv WHERE data like '%TMN PANTAI%'

Comment: I am searching the replacement for the query SELECT * FROM csv WHERE data like '%TMN PANTAI%'  . because its seaching speed is so slow and i have large database with 50 millions record.

Comment: Updated answer!

Comment: like clause effecting  the speed of searching

Comment: You can't search a phrase using ```match against query```. Using combination of both ```LIKE``` and ```match``` would be more efficient than just using ```LIKE```.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170454/discussion-between-manmeet-khurana-and-sandesh-gupta).